# How to run Background Task on IOS?

Tags: react-native

Two months after the project at Expo I realized that nothing sensible will come out of it.
I had to rewrite the whole project to pure RN. (the kind still pain)

The project stopped as soon as it came to background tasks.

On Android everything went smoothly. If anyone is interested I was helped by this module:

**react-native-background-job**

Unfortunately this module does not work is not compatible with iOS at the moment.
It is expected to start working on IOS 13.(Information from rn forum)

Began to try the analogs. Tried this :

**react-native-background-fetch**

But he only fetch. The task of my Tasca show notifications. He can't. Earlier in one of the topics offered:

**react-native-firebase**

Saying it as it pushes notification when the app is switched off.In my case he can hardly help.We have our own server.
There is still some **react-native-queue**. But I don't really understand how it works.It doesn't work for me.

Maybe someone faced with such a task. How did you decide ?

Comment: have you tried this library also? https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task

Comment: Its module only for Android.